# When uploading file, it show error message (PHP)

Tags: php

I try to upload a Image by using PHP. I need to save image in my database. this is my HTML file. I dont know how to pass data file

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
         <p>
           <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
           <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName">
        </p>

         <p>
           <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
           <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName">
        </p>

        <p>
           <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
           <input type="text" name="gender" id="Gender">
        </p>

         <p>
           <label for="Address">Address:</label>
           <input type="text" name="address" id="Address">
        </p>

         <p>
           <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
           <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
        </p>
         
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enctype='multipart/form-data'

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```